# SQL LEFT OUTER JOIN on Nullable column and the use of coalesce

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, left-join

I have a stored procedure that can retrieve results based on a user supplying a parameter for a particular type. The user can also supply a null parameter  in which case all results are returned and the filter is ignored.

Here is the stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE GetHousesByType
(
    @HouseTypeParameter INT = NULL,
)
AS 
BEGIN

SELECT HouseId, HouseType, HouseName
FROM HouseTable MAIN
LEFT JOIN HouseTypes HOTP ON MAIN.HouseType = HOTP.HouseTypeId
WHERE MAIN.HouseType = COALESCE(@HouseTypeParameter, MAIN.HouseType)
```

The problem is that sometimes the HouseType column that I join on can be null.

**I want to return all columns even if HouseType column is null but only if @HouseTypeParameter IS NULL**

---

Ive tried adding the following to the condition of the query

```
WHERE MAIN.HouseType = COALESCE(HouseType, MAIN.HouseType) OR MAIN.HouseType IS NULL
```

But this gets me null values no matter what the user sets the HouseType parameter to.

Any help would be great!

Comment: the `HouseType` column of which table can be `NULL`?

Comment: Whoops sorry Lamak good point. ill update the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless I'm missing something, this where clause should work for you:

```
WHERE MAIN.HouseType = COALESCE(@HouseTypeParameter, MAIN.HouseType)
OR (MAIN.HouseType IS NULL AND @HouseTypeParameter IS NULL)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a fictitious value to `HouseType` in case it's `NULL`:

```
WHERE COALESCE(MAIN.HouseType,-1) = COALESCE(@HouseTypeParameter, MAIN.HouseType, -1);
```

Or simply using an `OR`:

```
WHERE MAIN.HouseType = @HouseTypeParameter
OR @HouseTypeParameter IS NULL;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want

```
SELECT HouseId, HouseType, HouseName
FROM HouseTable MAIN
LEFT JOIN HouseTypes HOTP ON MAIN.HouseType = HOTP.HouseType
WHERE MAIN.HouseType = @HouseTypeParameter
    OR (MAIN.HouseType IS NULL AND @HouseTypeParameter IS NULL );
```